# critical section definition

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pthreads, critical-section

in this example code below, where is the "critical section" exatly?. after "sem_wait()" ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

void * thread_snd(void *arg);
void * thread_rcv(void *arg);
sem_t bin_sem;
int number=0;

char thread1[]="A Thread";
char thread2[]="B Thread";
char thread3[]="C Thread";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t t1, t2, t3;
    void *thread_result;
    int state;
    state = sem_init(&bin_sem, 0, 0);

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread_snd, &thread1);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread_rcv, &thread2);
    pthread_create(&t3, NULL, thread_rcv, &thread3);
    pthread_join(t1, &thread_result);
    pthread_join(t2, &thread_result);
    pthread_join(t3, &thread_result);
    printf("number : %d \n", number);
    sem_destroy(&bin_sem);

    return 0;
}

void * thread_snd(void * arg)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        while(number != 0)
            sleep(1);
        number++;
        printf("%s, number : %d \n", (char*)arg, number);
        sem_post(&bin_sem);
    }
}

void * thread_rcv(void * arg)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        sem_wait(&bin_sem);
        number--;
        printf("%s, number : %d \n", (char*)arg, number);
    }
}
```

Comment: void *thread_result is missing ;

Comment: It is very hard to reason about broken code.  Fix the potentially-infinite loop `while (number != 0) sleep(1);`

Answer (score 1):

There actually is no "critical section" in the provided code, there is only "sync point", and yes that is realized with the semaphore. The critical section can also be implemented with semaphore, but then the thread must use both `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` but in most cases mutexes are used for critical sections (if only one thread is ever supposed to enter it).